# Solve harmonic-factorial sequence with java recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to understand reqursion, but I have found one task, I couldn't solve for few days already.

X = 1/1 + 1/(1*2) + 1/(1*2*3) + 1/(1*2*3*4) + 1/(1*2*3*4*5) .....

how can I solve it for 100 repeats without conditional operators?

Can it be solved without recursion?

I've tried this code, but it doesn't work correctly and it contains "If".

```
public static double harFac(double n) {
    if (n == 1) return 1;
    return (1.0 / (n * harFac(n - 1))) + harFac(n - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could do something like this:

```
double result = 0;
int div = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    result += 1.0 / div; /*the division needs to take place in floating point*/
    div *= i+1; 
}
```

Comment: This question is about recursion not iteration.

Comment: Well he asked if it was possible to solve without recursion

Comment: Sorry, you may be right. "I can it be solved without recursion?" isn't really clear because of this "I" at start. Based on what I've seen on Stack Overflow over years it may also mean that OP may already know how to solve it without recursion (depending on how we correct that sentence). Will remove my vote if you edit your answer. Anyway it looks like your solution has a little problem since `1/div` is integer division so `1/2` will return `0` not `0.5`.

Comment: @Pshemo: I did that and fixed the **horrendous** integer division bug as well. Ain't I a nice cat?

Answer (score 1):

You'll very quickly run into trouble if you evaluate the denominator like that as it will run to a limit very quickly. When working with floating point, it's also a good idea to evaluate the smaller terms first.

Fortunately you can solve both of these problems by recasting the expression to

`1 * (1 + 1/2 * ( 1 + 1/3 * (1 + 1/4 * ( ... ) ) ) )`

So your final term is in the recursion is `foo = 1 + 1.0/100`, the penultimate term in the recursion is `1 + 1/98 * foo`, and so on.

I personally wouldn't use recursion to solve this, rather use a loop in a single function.

Answer (score 0):

You're along the right lines but you shouldn't be calling `harFac` twice. You need to instead calculate the divisor. I can't see how you would do this without an `if` condition, though.

```
public static double harFac(double n)
{
    if (n == 1) return 1;

    int divisor = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) divisor *= i;

    return (1.0 / divisor) + harFac(n - 1);
}
```

This doesn't work beyond around `n = 30` because the divisor becomes so massive.